# Performance of estimators

Tags: r, model-evaluation, regression

I have 11 different estimators and try to figure out which of them performs best. The regression line between given and estimated values ideally should have a slope of 1 and an intersect at 0,0; which would make it a perfect estimator. At least if the variance around the regression line is not too large (R2 value). Does anyone have suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could compute many indicators, based on errors. For example rmse, mae, mape ... you could create your own code or use some package, like `pracma`, `Metrics`, `sjmisc`, etc.

```
library(pracma)
b <- rep(1, 10)
x <- rnorm(10, 1, 0.1)
y <- runif(10,.99,1.01)
z <- (x+y)/2
apply(cbind(x,y,z),2,function(x)rmserr(x=x, y=b, summary = TRUE))
```